# Set color map in a StructuredGrid or PolyData in VTK?

Tags: c++, vtk

I am trying to create a color map for PolyData whose points make up the structure of  a nuclear reactor.It seems like every time I change color, the size of the cells change depending on the scalar value I assign to them. I just want a color map which shows interpolated color between the cells of my structure or even points.
This is the code that causes my color map to change the size of the cells.

```
#include <vtkFloatArray.h>
#include <vtkProperty.h>
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h>
#include <vtkInteractorStyleImage.h>
#include <vtkRenderer.h>
#include <vtkLookupTable.h>
#include <vtkPointData.h>
#include <vtkCubeSource.h>
#include <vtkPolyData.h>
#include <vtkGlyph3DMapper.h>


int main(){
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> points=//points used to set deminsions of grid
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();
    // cube source 
     vtkSmartPointer<vtkCubeSource> cube = 
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkCubeSource>::New();
     cube->SetZLength(2);
     //-----------------------------------------------
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> polydata =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New();
     points->Allocate(3136);
     for(int i=0;i<27;++i){
         if(i!=0){i+=1;}
        for(int j=4;j<12;++j){  
            points->InsertNextPoint(j, 0, (i)); 
        }
        for(int k=2;k<14;++k){
            points->InsertNextPoint(k, 1, i);
            }           
        for(int m=2;m<4;++m)                            
            for(int l=1;l<15;++l){
                points->InsertNextPoint(l, m, i);
                }
        for(int n=4;n<12;++n)
            for(int p=0;p<16;++p){
                points->InsertNextPoint(p, n, i);
                }
        for(int q=12;q<14;++q)  
            for(int r=1;r<15;++r){
                points->InsertNextPoint(r, q, i);
                }
        for(int s=2;s<14;++s){
            points->InsertNextPoint(s, 14, i);
            }
        for(int t=4;t<12;++t){
            points->InsertNextPoint(t, 15, i);
            }
        }
    //--------------------build scalor array--------------------------
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkFloatArray> sarray=
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkFloatArray>::New();
            sarray->SetNumberOfValues(3136);
            for(int i=0;i<3136;++i){
            if(i<2000)
                sarray->InsertValue(i,1);
            else
                sarray->InsertValue(i,10);
            }
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkLookupTable>cTable = 
           vtkSmartPointer<vtkLookupTable>::New();
    int tableSize =  10;// not sure if I need this
    cTable->SetNumberOfTableValues(tableSize);// not sure if I need this
    cTable->Build();
     //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    polydata->SetPoints(points);
    polydata->BuildCells();
    polydata->GetPointData()->SetScalars(sarray);
     //---------------------------------------------

      vtkSmartPointer<vtkGlyph3DMapper> mapper = 
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkGlyph3DMapper>::New();
     mapper->SetSourceConnection(cube->GetOutputPort());
    #if VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 5
      mapper->SetInputConnection(polydata->GetProducerPort());
    #else
      mapper->SetInputData(polydata);
    #endif
    mapper->Update();
    mapper->SetScalarRange(1, 10);
    mapper->SetLookupTable(cTable);
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> actor = 
     vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
    actor->SetMapper(mapper);
    actor->GetProperty()->SetPointSize(3);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer = 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow = 
     vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();

      renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);

      vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor = 
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();

      renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);

      renderer->AddActor(actor);
      renderer->SetBackground(.2, .3, .4);
      renderer->ResetCamera();
      renderWindow->Render();
      renderWindowInteractor->Start();

      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: What do we have to change to see the size changing?

Comment: Have you looked at this example? http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/PolyData/ColorCells